# Ngxs - How to prepopulate state on application load

Tags: ngxs

I would like to set the ngxs state on application load. What would be the best way to do this?

e.g. resolve the state object in an angular APP_INITIALIZER and then ???

Answer (score 2):

You could make the HTTP call to load data for the state via the `ngxsOnInit` lifecycle hook  see the lifecycle documentation [here](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/life-cycle#ngxsoninit).

In my usage of NGXS we've typically had our states respond to a particular action e.g. `UserLoggedIn` to load their initial data from an external service

We needed to wait on this action for two reasons:

- the HTTP services we called needed the auth token returned by Login to authenticate.
- in many cases the services would return 'default' data that was user specific.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I looked already on ngxsOnInit. What I dislike about is that you have to operate on the state slice level. I would like to set the global state (means data for several state classes).

Comment: Ah the whole store, sorry I didn't realise that from the question.
There's a couple of other APIs that could work for you - `reset` on the store, or a meta reducer plugin - have you looked at those in the NGXS docs?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `defaults` from the stat decorator (if it's the same one all the time on startup)or just populate the state in `APP_INITIALIZER` using normal `store.dispatch`

Comment: The initial data contains the whole state (means data managed via several state classes). "defaults" from @State decorator are not able to be populated with dynamic data (e.g. read via http). Firing several actions to populate state would be possible but seems a rather dirty approach. Currently I use an own AsyncStorageEngine implementation. But with this approach I am not really happy...